# Почему на телефоне загружается файл а на часах нет?

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Почему на телефоне идёт загрузка файла а при подключении к часам не хочет загружаться и как это исправить? То есть метод `getContrntDownlod()` если его объявить в `onCeate()` он срабатывает и скачивает файл, но когда я хочу чтобы он выполнялся в методе `launchPlayStoreOnWear()` если он приконектился к устройству, то так файл не загружает на часы.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final String apkURL = "http://test.wear-store.ru/";
    String apkName = "wearOs.apk";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);

        // storage runtime permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        image.setOnClickListener(view -> launchPlayStoreOnWear());
        getContentDownload();
    }

    private Node getConnectedNode() {
        Node returnNode = null;
        Task<List<Node>> wearableList = Wearable.getNodeClient(this).getConnectedNodes();
        try {
            List<Node> nodes = Tasks.await(wearableList);
            for (Node node : nodes) {
                if (node.isNearby()) {
                    returnNode = node;
                }
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnNode;
    }

    private void launchPlayStoreOnWear() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (getConnectedNode() != null) {
                RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
                remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(getContentDownload());

                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your watch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No watch is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public Intent getContentDownload() {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkURL));
        request.setTitle(apkName);
        request.setDescription("Downloading " + apkName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, apkName);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: "Не хочет загружаться" -- уточните, пожалуйста, в вопросе, что именно происходит. Есть ли ошибки в логах.

Comment: Описал детальнее